# how to run same databricks notebook from different job concurrently

Tags: scala, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a databricks notebook called X and I want to call this X notebook at the same time from two different jobs. The two different jobs for example A and B have their own job cluster.

In short:- I would like the notebook to run twice in parallel from 2 jobs. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the notebook to run twice in parallel from 2 jobs, or once when the 2 jobs get to a certain point?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @chen Hirsh :- I would like the notebook to run twice in parallel from 2 jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Databricks Jobs workflow** to achieve your requirement.

Go to **Workflows** -> **Create job** -> give name for your job.

[image]

Give your Notebook path and click on create. Do the same while creating the Second job as well.

Now, to run parallelly schedule both jobs at same time.

[image]

You can see my 2 jobs are running parallelly.

[image]